Why is angular velocity vector perpendicular to the velocity vector and position vector in uniform circular motion?
I am unable to understand if the angular velocity vector is always perpendicular to both the velocity vector and position vector how does it influence anything at all and what is it's significance. From my understanding if we take the components of this vector along any of the two vectors it would come out as 0 due to the 90° angle which just means it does not affect anything at all. Then just how is the velocity vector changing it's direction for the circular motion and what even is the physical significance of the angular velocity vector?

Angular velocity is naturally defined for rigid body, through the formula
$$\mathbf{v}_P - \mathbf{v}_Q = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times (\mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_Q) \ ,$$
relating the velocity of two material points $P$, $Q$ with their position difference through the angular velocity of the rigid body.
As you can easily see, from the definition of the vector product, the velocity difference $\mathbf{v}_P - \mathbf{v}_Q$ is orthogonal to both $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ and $\mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_Q$.
If you consider the point P performing a circular motion around a fixed point $Q$, s.t. $\mathbf{v}_Q = \mathbf{0}$, as a part of a fictitious (?) rigid body, you can easily see that the velocity of the point $P$ is orthogonal both to $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ and $\mathbf{r}_P - \mathbf{r}_Q$.

The definition of angular velocity is,
$\omega = \frac{r \times v}{r^2 }$
By definition, angular velocity vector is perpendicular to position vector and velocity vector.
This is by definition and doesn't mean that it is the source of the velocity direction change. You are right that "it does not affect anything at all". It is not like centrifugal force changing the velocity by Newton's Law. The reason to use angular velocity is for convenience to do a more complex problem analysis; you don't want to include velocity vector and position vector all the time in your derivations. Using angular velocity is more concise and beauty.

If you just consider one moving point  at location  r  and velocity v, the angular velocity is not interesting.
But if  you have a solid body  turning say your disk every point moves with different  velocity but the axes of rotation  is known, so you ascribe the  direction of the axes as direction  of the angular velocity and the change of angle per second as its magnitude.
The direction of the velocity vector changes by the centripetal acceleration this has not to do with angular velocity-
